# Ionic monitor a certain function even when the app is closed/ruunning in the background

Tags: javascript, mobile, plugins, background, ionic4

I am currently writing an ionic app that works with a raspberry pi tracking device that we have created. The device is connected to a web service that transmits the devices location to my mobile app and i have set it to notify me when the device has gone a certain distance away from my current location with a push notification but this will only work if the app is currently open and in the foreground. Is there a way for me to let this function run even if the app is not currently in the foreground? I have looked at the Ionic and cordova-plugin-background-mode plugin butt it is in beta phase and apparently has some issues. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Edit: Sorry there is not much code but i don't have anything to present to you at this moment.

Comment: If there is maybe a javascript way that could aschieve that would be great but i am not sure if that would work in a mobile app